# Codeigniter inserting data ( with insert function )

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have simple model, that needs to inset data to my table. All works fine when i use sql and query but when i try to use insert function i get an error that i need to use set ??

id in my database is auto increment and date is time stamp

```
class Article extends CI_Model {

private $id;
private $title;
private $text;
private $date;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

public function save_article($title,$text)
{
    $this->title=$title;
    $this->text=$text;
    $this->id='';
    $this->load->helper('date');
    $this->date=now();
    print_r($this);
    //"INSERT INTO article VALUES ('','".$title."','".$text."',NOW())")
    $this->db->insert('articles',$this);
}
}
```

> Article Object ( [id:Article:private] => [title:Article:private] =>
>   rrrrrrrrrrr [text:Article:private] => rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
>   [date:Article:private] => 1351680951 )
>
> A Database Error Occurred
>
> You must use the "set" method to update an entry.
>
> Filename: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\blog\system\database\DB_active_rec.php
>
> Line Number: 1174

Comment: It might be that your `id` database field is unique, and there is already an `id` with the value `''`.

Comment: my id in db is unique and AUTO_INCREMENT ! it does not need to insert that value , i tried without setting id but again i was getting same error

Comment: where is db defined? You use this but it is not in the constructor...try setting this->id = false

Comment: you must set the data using set() before insert the data into database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your member variables in `Article` are `private`. The Active Record class cannot read them using `get_object_vars`.

```
private $id;
private $title;
private $text;
private $date;
```

Make them as `public` or pass in an array of key-value pairs to `insert`.